# PHP to get content in an onclick event

Tags: php, javascript, html, get, onclick

I have a page source like this:

```
<div class="ajax-checklist-widget"><div id="ShowResultsLabel" class="ajax-checklist-select" onclick="showproductlist(17342171, 545763, 'ShowResultsList')">
    <div class="ajax-checklist-select-control">
        <span rel="0" class="ajax-checklist-select-value">This is something</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click on `This is something` in the browser, a list of options is displayed. I want to get these options using PHP using `file_get_contents` but unfortunately these options are not in the webpage source code.

Anyone know how to retrieve these options?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry everyone, i'm not sure if the title is correct for my problem

Comment: ya, you could just have the php do this on load, and then echo out a javascript array to the page (which you can reference in the onclick).

Comment: Where are these options?

Comment: @Itehnological Many users on SO have few or no answers. Putting back into the StackOverflow community is great, but if one doesn't have the expertise to do so, that may well come in the form of reputation given from upvotes and **accepted answers** (hint to OP) `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the options are changed dynamically, normally is done by ajax.

Try find out which url are sending the option values. You can do this using the firebug to see the XHR connections in the Net tab, or another similar debug from another browser.

When you get the url, that sent the option values, make the `file_get_content` directly to it, with the same parameters sent in the XHR.